# updating Silverlight application @ website

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I have the following scenario: a Silverlight application (constructed to be OOB) embedded at an ASP.NET website where, if the user already installed it, a label saying that is displayed; otherwise, an install button appears. Eventually I can update the .xap file available in the website.

Now the problem: if the user executes the application through his Desktop/Start Menu, i'm able to update the application and suggest the user to restart it. But, if I update the .xap file and upload it again to the website, apparently no "Silverlight update" occurs, it is displayed as a new application (if the user install it again, an application icon is displayed at his desktop).

Is there something I'm missing or there's nothing to do about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Signing the Silverlight application solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you run in a browser, updates are picked up right away (subject to HTTP caching rules).  With OOB apps you need to use the **App.Current.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync()** method in your app to have it update.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.checkanddownloadupdateasync(v=vs.95).aspx

The only drawback is that there is no way to just check for an update and give the users an option to download it conditionally; calling this always updates it if there is an update.  You can however hook into the event and find info about the update should you wish.  See this resource for more information: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/180931/408554.aspx